# Personal NAS Storage

Tags: nas

I am looking for a NAS that compatible with Windows Mac and Linux(ubuntu) has a plug in architecture, Raid support and supports 5+ bays. I currently am using windows home sever which I have not had much luck with (Corrupts all data during data transfer) and was wondering if the super user community had any advice on the best NAS currently on the market.

Answer (score 1):

I would also look in to OpenFiler before going with FreeNAS.

http://blog.patyuen.com/lessons/technology/openfiler-vs-freenas-tips-for-building-your-own-nas/

If you want hardware you can look into [Drobo](http://www.drobo.com/products/index.php) line of RAID devices. Great products and provide hardware RAID at lower prices than some products.

Answer (score 0):

As for software, I would recommend FreeNAS.  You can build any hardware you like (to accommodate your 5 bay need).  I also tried WHS but was not pleased with it at all.  I installed freeNAS and haven't looked back.